# add click event to many control

Tags: c#, .net

I have many controls in my form. for example 120 labels in one panel. and i want when user clicked on each label just call same function with same parameter.
Now i used like this :

```
        private void label67_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeToTextbox(sender);
    }

    private void label66_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeToTextbox(sender);
    }

    private void label65_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeToTextbox(sender);
    }

    private void label64_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeToTextbox(sender);
    }
```

now can i make easy way to call ChangeToTextbox function when user clicked in any label?

Comment: web? windows? and also, why would you tag c# code with vb.net??

Comment: @walther I don't think this is VB.net

Comment: @christopher, because it isn't, but it was tagged as such before I edited it (thus my complaint)

Comment: I apologise! I read this as the other way around. :)

Comment: @walther - some people are happy to receive a solution in either language which is why this *may* have been tagged with both. Having said that, in this case the syntax for adding handlers is somewhat different so C# is probably more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the same OnClick handler for all labels on the panel:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(l => l.Click += label_Click);
}

private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeToTextbox(sender);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find all your controls then just add the handler via code;

```
List<Control> controls = GetAllMyControls();
foreach(Control control in controls)
{
   control.OnClick += (o, e) => { ChangeToTextBox(o); }
}
```

The syntax should be very similar for both web and winform solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily achieved by using following approach: Pls give a try,

1) Go to Windows Forms Designer and click the first Label control to select it. Then hold down the CTRL key while you click each of the other labels to select them. Be sure that every label is selected.

2) Then go to the Events page in the Properties window. Scroll down to the Click event, and type label_Click in the box

3) Press ENTER. The IDE adds a Click event handler called label_Click() to the code, and hooks it to each of the labels.

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ChangeToTextbox(sender);
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553231.aspx